# catch exception while a calling a function from different .py file

Tags: python-3.x, file, subprocess, try-catch, os.system

I have a main_etl.py and watcher.py

main_etl.py

```
def test_function():
    try:
        do sometihng....
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

def main(arg1='', arg2='', arg3=''):
    try:
        test_function()
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
```

watcher.py

```
import main_etl

def main_function():
    try:
        main_etl.main(arg1='', arg2='', arg3='')

    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    else:
        do something....
```

And I am running - python watcher.py

I tried the above code, But it didn't catch any exception in the watcher.py file
I wanted to catch the exception in the calling function script (watcher.py).

Can anyone suggest me like how to catch this error or is there any other way of implementing this.

I know os.system() and subprocess.call(), But how can I call the main() function inside main_etl.py ?

Comment: When you say it didn't catch any exception in watcher.py - what exactly did happen?

Comment: @slothrop, It only prints the error, So Ideally, if any exception occurs, It shouldn't be going to the else part right. But it does

Comment: As soon as you catch an exception in watcher.py, you `raise e`, so you're propagating the exception up to the caller.  If `watcher.main_function()` is your entry point, then that means the exception will halt the interpreter and print its traceback - could that be what you are seeing? You're right that if an exception is caught, the `else` clause should not execute.